# Polyline shifting algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, gdi+, polyline

I have a list with polylines (PointCollection) like shown in the graphic. Some segments are overlapping like the blue and orange line as shown in “original”. I already know which segments these are. I need to shift the overlapping segments apart. The tricky thing is to avoid new overlapping with other lines like shown in “wrong”.

[image]

I've the problem, that I've just the coordinates of the nodes and no information about the segments. Is there any possibility to determine whether I shift a node on a segment of another line? Have someone a good Idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - How do you want to shift? Manually or in code? Which direction? Randomly? You can write a trial and error routine that uses the same test to check for overlapping as the one you have to find overlapping in the first place. (Hint you can make the polylines into graphicspaths, and combine them into a region which can be tested for isempty)

Comment: I prepare the data for a third party tool and I won’t visualise it in my application. The goal is to shift the node by code. My idea is to shift the nodes either to the left or to the right in the direction of the angle bisector between two segments. Before I shift the node I would like to test which direction is empty. How can I convert polylines into graphicspaths?

Comment: You can use GDI+ graphics and still export just the results without actually displaying anything, althugh for testing the routines a small winforms project may be a good idea... you simply add the point arrray to an emptygraphicspath: `gp.AddLines(pointlist.ToArray())`. To move a GP use a Matrix and gp.tranform! Create a Region from one gp and test with reg.Intersect(gp2) and if (reg.IsEmtpy(graphics object))..

Comment: Do note though that this solution would dpend on the pixel resolution of the Graphics object you create. So maybe an analytical solution is called for; for this you would test segment intersection geometrically. There are quite a few posts on line intersection around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments you have a choice of

- solving the issue analytically by geometric calculations or of
- using some GDI+ methods

Here is an example of the latter:

First your Console application needs to include a reference to `System.Drawing` and a few using clauses:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;  //optional, used for bitmap saving only
```

Here is a static function that tests if two `GraphicsPaths` intersect:

```
static bool intersect(GraphicsPath gp1, GraphicsPath gp2, Graphics g) 
{
    using (Region reg = new Region(gp1))
    {
        reg.Intersect(gp2);
        return !reg.IsEmpty(g);
    }
}
```

It takes two `GraphicsPaths` and aslo a `Graphics` object.

Here is a testbed to demonstrate how one can use it. It creates 2 random polylines and then shifts the second to the right by 50 pixels each time until it no longer intersects the 1st one.

All stages are drawn into a bitmap which then gets saved..:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int w = 1234;
    int h = 1234;

    Random rnd = new Random(0);
    for (int t = 0; t < 33; t++)
    {
        List<Point> l1 = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> l2 = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            l1.Add(new Point(rnd.Next(1234), rnd.Next(567)));
            l2.Add(new Point(rnd.Next(567), rnd.Next(1234)));
        }

        using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h))
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        using (GraphicsPath gp1 = new GraphicsPath())
        using (GraphicsPath gp2 = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            gp1.AddLines(l1.ToArray());
            gp2.AddLines(l2.ToArray());
            m.Translate(50, 0);
            bool intersects = intersect(gp1, gp2, g);
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.DrawPath(Pens.Blue, gp1);
            g.DrawPath(intersects ? Pens.Red : Pens.Green, gp2);

            while (intersects)
            {
                gp2.Transform(m);
                intersects = intersect(gp1, gp2, g);
                g.DrawPath(intersects ? Pens.Red : Pens.Green, gp2);
                intersects = intersect(gp1, gp2, g);
            }


            bmp.Save(@"D:\scrape\x\__xTest_" + t.ToString("000") + ".png", 
                     ImageFormat.Png);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the output files:

[image]

You can access the shifted path points as

```
 List<PointF> l3 = gp2.PathPoints.ToList();
```

Note that you should either make the `Bitmap` large enough for your actual numbers or scale them down and work with `floats`!

Comment: Ok, I like your approach with GDI+. Thank you for the example. My idea is to populate the plane first with the lines which have no intersections. Then I pick the first of an overlapping pair (for example the blue one) and draw it also. Next I pick the second one (the orange one) and shift it to the right. Then I compare it with the already drawn lines to check if I have still intersections. If so I shift it to the left and repeat the check. Is this a good approach? Is it possible to compare one GraphicsPath with the already drawn GraphicsPath in the plane to check for intersections?

Comment: Sure, just put them in  a `List<GraphicsPath>` and loop over it. Note that I only draw them to demo the idea; you don't need to do any actual drawing.. You do need the `Graphics` object though to call the function, so you also need a `Bitmap`; but all the drawing itself isn't necessary!